# Error: Get http://unix.socket/1.0: dial unix /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket: connect: permission denied

Tags: lxd

I am getting the following error while connecting to LXD:

`Error: Get http://unix.socket/1.0: dial unix /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket: connect: permission denied`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will have to execute the following command in order to provide access to the current (non-root) user:

```
sudo usermod -a -G lxd $(whoami)
newgrp lxd
```

Confirm it by executing

```
/snap/bin/lxc query --wait -X GET /1.0
```

You should get a JSON response.

Comment: You'll also have to logout and login again after the `usermod` command.

Comment: @RogerDueck why?

Comment: `newgrp lxd` should come *after* the `usermod` command.  That solves the problem.

Comment: @RogerDueck feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: I tried, but it says "Suggested edit queue is full".  Can you clear it?

Comment: Probably a SO thing https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345125/suggested-edit-queue-is-full

Comment: My user is already a member of 'lxd', so this isn't it, for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the below commands:-

1. Add an existing user to group lxd.

   `sudo adduser {your-username} lxd`
2. Change the current group ID during a login session.

   `newgrp lxd`
3. Check the attached group to the user.

   `id`

   `lxc list`

Comment: This is a slightly different command to perform the same fix as is already described by another answer some two years earlier.